# Setting up cout support in structs with multiple layers of inheritance

Tags: c++, cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Printable abstract
{
 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& cout, const Printable& obj)
 {
  obj.print(cout);

  return cout;
 }

 virtual void print(std::ostream& cout) const = 0;
};

struct VirtualBase abstract : public Printable
{
 //stuff
};

struct Named abstract : public Printable
{
 std::string name;

 void print(std::ostream& cout) const
 {
  cout << "Name: " << name;
 }
};

struct DerivedA : public VirtualBase
{
 void print(std::ostream& cout) const
 {
  cout << "DerivedA";
 }
};

struct DerivedB : public VirtualBase, public Named
{
 void print(std::ostream& cout) const
 {
  cout << "DerivedB";

  dynamic_cast<const Named*>(this)->print(cout);
  //Is there a better way to call Named::print?
 }
};
```

Since DerivedB inherits VirtualBase and Named, and both of those inherit Printable, I can't use DerivedB with cout.  What would be the best way to have Printable support on multiple layers of the inheritance hierarchy?  Also, what would be the simplest way to call Named::print in a derived class's print?

Comment: What's with the `abstract` in your struct declarations? That isn't valid C++.

Comment: @DavidBrown: Unless he made it as a macro.

Comment: @Linux Ah yes. If so you might want to include it in your code sample and making it all caps as is standard for macros to avoid confusion user173342.

Comment: Oh, it's for VC++ 2010.  You can ignore the abstract if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `DerivedB` is a `VirtualBase` (which is a `Printable`), and a `Named` (which is a `Printable`), so the `operator<<` tries to convert `DerivedB` to a `Printable`, but can't downcast, because it is *two* `Printable` objects, and it doesn't know which to downcast to.  Since you only want `DerivedB` to derive from *one* `Printable` object, you have to use **virtual inheritance**.

```
   normal inheritance:            virtual inheritance:
Printable      Printable                 Printable
   |               |                    /        \
VirtualBase      Named          VirtualBase      Named
       \         /                     \         /
        DerivedB                         DerivedB
```

Which is done simply:

```
struct Named abstract : virtual public Printable
struct VirtualBase abstract : virtual public Printable
```

Note that a class with virtual inheritance is larger and *slightly* slower than it would be without, but on the other hand, C++ is one of the very few languages *that can do it at all*.

Comment: Still gives me the C2594 ambiguity error with `struct Named abstract : virtual public Printable`, also tried putting a virtual for DerivedB's Named inheritance and still no go.

Comment: Ok, if I do virtual on both VirtualBase and Named for inheriting Printable, it compiles (and works right)!  But it has to be both, not one like your example.

Comment: @user173342: I thought it only had to be one, but maybe my memory is off.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to qualify which `print` you want to call with the scope resolution operator (`::`) like so:

```
Named::print(cout);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves one problem, but it still can't compile due to the ambiguity in DerivedB's Printable inheritance.

Comment: @user173342 It compiles fine for me. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/01/19/60166.aspx) seems to indicate however that C++/CLI does not support multiple inheritance like this. If you're targeting C++/CLI you should add that to your question.

Comment: I am not using the /clr tag (set to No Common Language Runtime Support)... Doesn't that cause VC++ 2010 to not use C++/CLI?

Comment: @user173342 I think so. I'm afraid I have little experience with VC++ however :(

Comment: DavidBrown: He's not using CLR, since he says he's _not_ using the tag, and if he were, it would be a compile error.  That being said, this answer solves what he asks, but not his ambiguity problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to fix it by templating the operator overload:

```
 template<typename P> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& cout, const P& obj)
 {
  obj.print(cout);

  return cout;
 }
```

I'm not sure how stable this is, though.

Comment: @MooingDuck Just out of curiosity, what terrible things would it do?  And do you know an alternative?

Comment: I posted the correct answer to your problem.  The problem from your code comes from classes that do _not_ derive from `Printable` attempting to use your function, and probably failing.  Namely, _every template class_.

Comment: I suppose that would be unfortunate.